# List agents connected to elastic cloud

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

Lets say we have number of nodes(machines) shipping logs to elastic cloud using any beats(filebeat,metric beat).

Is there any consolidated data in elastic cloud where I can see the list of nodes which are connected to it to ship the logs ?

Comment: you want to see how many and which nodes are sending data to elastic right ?

Comment: In [Stack Monitoring > Beats](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/beats-page.html) you can see all the beats connected and shipping logs with their health and metrics

Comment: Thank you @SagarPatel, this is the sort of information I was looking for, but seems this is available only if we are monitoring the beats.

Comment: You must monitor the beats in order to get that info.
In kibana: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/beats-page.html
For beats: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/monitoring-internal-collection.html